# WP7 Alert dialog

Tags: windows-phone-7, alert

I've seen applications on WP7 that seem to use a control that dims the app, plays a quick sound, and shows a dialog at the top of the screen.  What is this control called as I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

Try [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949(v=VS.95).aspx)

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
```

Comment: Hi Amc, the diming you've observed would be coded independently of MessageBox.Show. ie. that's not out of the box behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx) is a more flexible version of `MessageBox`